# How to change history size for ever?

Tags: command-line

The default size of history in Ubuntu is 1000 but it's too small. I want to change it to 10000, So I append

```
export HISTSIZE=10000
export HISTFILESIZE=10000
```

to '~/.profile'
and 'source' it

```
source .profile
```

then I run

```
echo $HISTSIZE
echo $HISTFILESIZE
```

1000 was displayed for both but I reboot my computer it went 'default'.
Why doesn't it work?

Comment: You have a typo here in the question: `export HISEFILESIZE=10000` (although it seems you didn't in your `.profile` if the echos worked). Just in case someone looks at it here, it should be `HISTFILESIZE`

Answer (score 129):

I tried the same thing, only to discover that sneaky Ubuntu sets these variables in `~/.bashrc` by default, which is executed instead of `~/.profile` for non login shells such as just opening a terminal window. Changing these lines in `~/.bashrc` fixed it for me:

```
# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000
```

Comment: hisfilesize is in KB?

Comment: @duckx No, HISTFILESIZE is in *number of line* stored in the history *file*, while HISTSIZE is the *number of line* stored and available by each shell process (and then saved to HISTFILESIZE). Note that with no value  (or non-number, or negative), then no limiting occurs.

Comment: This does not work for some reason on XFCE Terminal

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz: could be fixed by writing `/etc/bash.bashrc` if that's acceptble to you. See below. (maybe it was also the missing `export`)

Comment: Don't forget if you're using ZSH to throw it in your `~/.zshrc` If you're on a modern version of Mac OS you may not even have a `.bashrc` ;)

Comment: @vaab: According to `man bash`, the default value of `HISTSIZE` is 500 commands: "The shell sets the default value to 500 after reading any startup files."

Answer (score 74):

## [From the Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-HISTFILESIZE):

```
HISTSIZE 
    The maximum number of commands to remember on the history list.

    If the value is 0, 
       **commands are not saved** in the history list. 

    Numeric values less than zero result in 
       every command being saved on the history list (there is no limit).
```

So for an infinite *history list*, make: 
HISTSIZE=(some number **less than 0**)

```
HISTFILESIZE 
    The maximum number of lines contained in the history file. 

    When this variable is assigned a value, 
        the history file is truncated, if necessary, 
        to contain no more than that number of lines 
        by removing the oldest entries. 

        The history file is also truncated to this size after 
        writing it when a shell exits. 

    If the value is 0, 
        **the history file is truncated to zero size.** 

    Non-numeric values and numeric values less than zero 
        inhibit truncation.
```

So for an infinite `.bash_history` *history file*, make: 
HISTFILESIZE=(some number **less than 0**)

Answer (score 18):

As mentioned by [@Michal Przybylowicz](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307541/how-to-change-history-size-for-ever/307568#comment1054374_307568), these files seem to be ignored in Xubuntu (and Lubuntu) sometimes. If so, you could instead **write the lines**

> ```
> export HISTSIZE=10000
> export HISTFILESIZE=10000
> ```

**to `/etc/bash.bashrc`**. This will change these environment variables' values globally.

Comment: Your two lines could be reduced to just `HISTSIZE=10000` since `export` is not necessary for Bash variables in `.bashrc` and because if `HISTFILESIZE` is unset, it takes its value from `HISTSIZE`. From [`man bash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-HISTFILESIZE): "The shell sets the default value to the value of HISTSIZE after reading any startup files."