# Command history count stuck at 2000

Tags: command-line, bash, prompt

I have custom PS1 bash prompt which includes command history count. It has work flawlessly for weeks, but today I noticed it's stuck at 2000. When I execute command, it gets to 2001 as it's supposed, but when I close terminal and open it again, it's again 2000.
I don't remember doing any changes to terminal configuration. This problem occurs in gnome-terminal and xfce4-terminal as well.

Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible your history size is stuck at 2000?  See here... http://askubuntu.com/questions/307541/how-to-change-history-size-for-ever

Comment: Seems likely seems the default cap does seem to be 2000. OP: Edit `~/.bashrc` and change `HISTSIZE` and `HISTFILESIZE` to a have no value.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Could you copy your comment into answer so I can mark it as solved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add to your ~/.bashrc:

```
export HISTFILESIZE=20000
export HISTSIZE=20000
```

And you'll have 20k as limit.

> HISTSIZE is the number of lines or commands that are stored in memory
>   in a history list while your bash session is ongoing.
>
> HISTFILESIZE is the number of lines or commands that (a) are allowed
>   in the history file at startup time of a session, and (b) are stored
>   in the history file at the end of your bash session for use in future
>   sessions. (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19454838/1013183))