# Are the HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE generic or specific to .bash_history

Tags: bash, bashrc, postgresql

[How to change history size for ever?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307541/how-to-change-history-size-for-ever)

So I wanted to add a follow up question to this post but wasn't sure if posting on it was allowed or would be useful since its so old.

My question is does setting the `HISTSIZE` and `HISTFILESIZE` work for all files?

I have a `.bash_history` and a `psql_history` and I want both to keep large chunks (10000 entries) of my records does setting the size in my `.bashrc` do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HISTFILE` and `HISTFILESIZE` are `bash` specific (some other shells might also support the same/similar environment variables e.g. `zsh` supports `HISTFILE` and uses `SAVEHIST` instead of `HISTFILESIZE`) and dictates `bash`'s interactive history, by default; it would not work for `psql` CLI's history.

Look out for any such specific directive that `psql` provides, and that you can set on any startup configuration file, or via an environment variable, or may be via command line.

Comment: Zsh and mksh have only `HISTSIZE` and `HISTFILE`, and no `HISTFILESIZE`.

Comment: @muru `SAVEHIST` it is ...edited...