# How display over 1000 commands history?

Tags: command-line, bash, 20.04, history

I am working on a project that have reached over more than 3000 commands. However most of the commands of mine is repeated and generated automatically due to my program.

I have try to grep or export to file but it only displays 1000 commands recently.

Are there any ways that to have a look on those very first commands (for e.g first 500 commands).

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You can set it in the `.bashrc` file. Use `HISTSIZE=100000` or any number You want. Remember to re-login after the change. More info check [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307541/how-to-change-history-size-for-ever/690870#690870)

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz many thanks ! :D I will check it out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My new settings I have recently found and used.

```
zeus@buster-raspi:~$ cat .bashrc
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

snip ....

# New history settings  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1288/preserve-bash-history-in-multiple-terminal-windows

export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth:erasedups  # no duplicate entries edited to ignore the blank line start too
export HISTSIZE=100000                   # big big history
export HISTFILESIZE=100000               # big big history
shopt -s histappend                      # append to history, don't overwrite it

# Save and reload the history after each command finishes
export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -c; history -r; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```