# Reviewing history of inputs and outputs

Tags: input, output, history

I closed my previous session on Ubuntu and when I logged back in, I realized I wanted a screenshot of my previous outputs. I used `history` and that only gave me my last 50 previous inputs. Is there any way for me to retrieve the outputs from my previous session or is that lost? I am new at this and my knowledge only extends up to moving around files and manipulating them a bit :(

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454837/bash-histsize-vs-histfilesize

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change history size for ever?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307541/how-to-change-history-size-for-ever)